# C# Log into website using live.com auth and download page

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, office365

I would like to login website using live.com auth (office 365) and download source code of page.

I cannot use:

```
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("loginname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
```

because I cannot create app password (forbidden by our company) and we are using MFA auth

I can use:

```
var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
ClientContext clientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteURL);
```

but ClientContext is null (its not sharepoint site - its only site using live.com (office 365) auth)

I am thinking about log in to our sharepoint site get credentials and then open non-sharepoint site, but these combination not working. On browser it allowed me without repeat login.

```
string site = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/";
string site2 = "non-sharepoint site";

var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
ClientContext clientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(site);
var credentials = clientContext.Credentials;

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
    client.Credentials = credentials;
    var page = client.DownloadString(site2);
    Console.WriteLine(page);
}
```

Output is:

```
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://aadcdn.msauth.net" crossorigin>
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msauth.net">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msftauth.net">
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by CoreWebView2 class with Edge.